# $_POST is not working in web services?

Tags: php, ios, web-services, api, webservice-client

I am stuck from 2 days, I am working with web services and this web services is make request from `iOS`, They are send request with `$_POST` method but it is not working.

I tried to `print_r($_POST)` but its return blank `Array()` and also try with `$_REQUEST` but its return blank `Array()` only `GET` method work proper.

I also make `<form>` and try to submit with `POST` method and print both `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` then both are work proper.

When print `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` then it return `GET`.

Please guys any one known how it happen ?

Comment: No code? No solution... Can you share some relevant code? ;)

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help if you don't post your code in the question? Is this meant to be a _guessing game_?

Comment: From your description you are not sending the request via POST or you are doing something wrong when sending the request which makes it go via GET. PHP will not inexplicably change an incoming POST request to GET.

Comment: I am using web services they this web service is send request from iOS device. I am just print `$_POST`  and it will return blank

Comment: @apokryfos , I am send request from POSTMAN with POST method.

Comment: So you are saying that it leaves POSTMAN as POST but arrives at PHP as GET?

Comment: yes @apokryfos , thanks bro to understand

Comment: Can you share your request header here?

Comment: @apokryfos  Cache-Control →max-age=172800
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →70
Content-Type →text/html
Date →Mon, 24 Oct 2016 06:28:00 GMT
Expires →Wed, 26 Oct 2016 06:28:00 GMT
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=100
Server →Apache
Vary →Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Via →HTTP/1.1 sophos.http.proxy:3128

Comment: Just edit your question with the raw request. It's impossible to understand it as a comment. Also that looks like the response header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126504/discussion-between-mayank-vadiya-and-apokryfos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I am able to find my answer and issue. For `mod_rewrite` is change request method. If you have a rewrite rule that affects the action URL, you will not able to read the POST variable.

You have to add this rule to `.htaccess` , at the beginning, to avoid to rewrite the url:

`RewriteRule ^login.php - [PT]`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we would need to see your code to be able to help you fully. Below is a little example of how to use forms in combination with PHP and `$_POST`.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;
}
?>

<!-- HTML -->
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="element" />
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Here is web service not form.

Comment: Same principle in handling, though you will need to supply us with some sample code in order for us to help.

Comment: I tried with your example its work fine... I am stuck with webservice bro